# CocoaPods 'pod lib create' not generating Podfile

Tags: cocoapods, cocoapods-1.0.1

I've previously (and successfully) been able to create a Pod before running:

```
"pod lib create os-nsthreading"
```

But since updated to 1.0.1 the script seems to fail in creating Podfile, thus not creating the required .workspace file:

```
What language do you want to use?? [ Swift / ObjC ]> ObjC

Would you like to include a demo application with your library? [ Yes / No ]
 > Yes

Which testing frameworks will you use? [ Specta / Kiwi / None ]
 > None

Would you like to do view based testing? [ Yes / No ]
 > No

What is your class prefix?
 > OS

Running pod install on your new library.

[!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory.
```

I've attempted to update CocoaPods again - but still to no avail - my first thought was permissions, but it seems to create the project files okay...
Any point in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround, (it does appear to create the Podfile infact) just re-run the 'pod install' and it completes the job....

Answer (score 0):

Authors suggest to use last available build of cocoapods prerelease version **if** you are using `Xcode 8` and `Swift 3` project. Currently it's a `1.1.0.rc.2` version.

For downloading prerelease version run `gem install cocoapods --pre` in terminal.

Hope it helps! 

Artem

Comment: @popctrl I've answered similar question with more detailed explanation. Try this one. - http://stackoverflow.com/a/39805768/4211944