# Creating a pod with cocoapods fails

Tags: cocoapods

I've just tried to create a pod using `pod lib create Test` and went with all the defaults. However, when it is done asking me questions I get:

> Running pod install on your new library.
>
> [!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory.
>
> Ace! you're ready to go!
>   We will start you off by opening your project in Xcode
>     open 'Test/Example/Test'
>   The file /Users/macattack/Documents/Xcode/Test/Example/Test.xcworkspace does not exist.

I don't understand what I've done wrong.

I'm using XCode 8, cocoapods 1.1.0.rc.2.

Answer (score 0):

*Following is working on Cocoapods **1.1.0.rc.2** version.*

You haven't done anything wrong. It's a pre-release version, just a few more steps required. 
Podfile is already there, but in the Example folder. Open terminal, proceed to Example folder:

```
cd [path]
```

You can just drag&drop the folder after 'cd' letters to paste the path. 
Then just run `pod install`.
Open workspace, Xcode will prompt you to update to last Swift syntax version and update version property.

If you are using **Swift 3** there is another option, suggested by authors ([Issue 5841](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/5841)).

1. Create a .swift-version file in pod parent folder. Run `echo "3.0" >> .swift-version`
2. Create pod with `pod lib create [pod name]`.
3. Proceed to pod Example folder and run `pod install`

Hope it helps!

Artem